# How to configure commons-logging for JUnit testing of Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, logging, junit

I'm trying to debug some hibernate functionality in a spring app with a junit test and commons logging, but I can't seem to get anything other than the default INFO messages to appear. I'm also running these junit tests from Eclipse.

I've had no luck from the spring forums either.

I'm particularly interested in the debug logging output by Hibernate (to try and figure out why it takes 23 seconds to run this test).

Current output shows the default setting of INFO:

```
Mar 29, 2011 4:44:35 PM org.springframework.test.AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests onSetUp
INFO: Began transaction: transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager@5f873eb2]; defaultRollback true
testGetSubjectsForSite time: [00:00:00:068]
Mar 29, 2011 4:44:58 PM org.springframework.test.AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests endTransaction
INFO: Rolled back transaction after test execution
```

I've tried to add a commons-logging.properties file to the classpath (the same location as the hibernate.properties and test-components.xml) but still only the default INFO messages appear.

Here's the commons-logging.properties file:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger

# handlers
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

# default log level
.level=FINE
org.springframework.level=FINE
org.hibernate.level=FINE

# level for the console logger
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Is anyone able to shed any light on why I can't get the DEBUG messages to print out? Is there a logging setting I'm missing?

**Edit:** I've tried FINEST and DEBUG to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems the logging configuration file used by Jdk14Logger should be specified at runtime.
See the following file in your JDK directory: JDK_HOME/jre/lib/logging.properties (it's the default one used if no config file is found)
Moreover, the file path should be absolute, otherwise it's relative to the folder where the JRE is executed - see the code of java.util.logging.LogManager.readConfiguration()

Also see:
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=143
http://cyntech.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/how-to-use-commons-logging/

Answer (score 0):

Your default and hibernate logging is at Level "FINE" which is more of a "INFO" in log4j terms.

You need set DEBUG level for org.hibernate which in JDK logging is equal to 'FINEST'

Set 
org.hibernate.level=FINEST (in the above log which should enable debug logs)

Comment: I'm not using log4j... I'm using jdk14Logger. FINE should be correct for debug messages. To confirm this, I tried FINEST and it still didn't work. Thanks anyway.